# In magento how i set index page and home page as a same link

Tags: navigation, magento-1.7, magento

I have a navigation menu:-
home aboutus test summery

I am working in magento.now when i load index page it shows different page from 'home' menu page. i just need to link both pages. i mean when i load index page then 'home'menu page should be load.

Answer (score 1):

From the Magento Knowledge Base:

> 1. In the Admin Panel, select System > Configuration.
> 2. Click the Web tab in the left side panel located under the General section.
> 3. Expand the Default Pages bar to display the following options.
> 4. In the CMS Home Page drop-down menu, select the page you wish to set as your web store home page.
> 5. Click Save to save your changes.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-change-the-home-page